# Xamarin check internet connection

Tags: android, xamarin

I have to check internet connection in my application, fallowing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out)
I have added lines to my manifest file. However I have an issue with `getSystemServiceMethod` it is not defined in my case, context does not contain such a method.

As well I`ve been trying to do something like this:

```
public static bool isInternetOn()
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)Context.ConnectivityService;
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;
    bool isWifi = networkInfo.Type == ConnectivityType.Wifi; // wifi check
    return networkInfo.IsConnected;
}
```

But it throws an exception. How could I fix this issue and check whether the phone has access to the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You could pass the `Context` as parameter of `isInternetOn`.

or

2. Use `connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)(Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService));`

or

3. Better than the above ones, you should use the [ConnectivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin)

Your code have a bug, you must check `networkInfo` nullity.
It should look like this:

```
public static bool isInternetOn()
{
    var connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)(Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService));
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.IsConnected;
}
```

**FINAL NOTE:**

Your implementation don't cover all the cases, please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4239019/5223160).
You should use [ConnectivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin).